# rshiny mainpanel pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, shiny

I have my rshiny app ready. Now I want to export the page into pdf. I want below:

1. Export the full shiny output to pdf, like save a page to pdf in Chrome with page scaling option.
2. Exporting only the mainPanel to pdf (no sidebarPanel) with page scaling option. In the mainPanel I have 2 tables and 5 charts.
3. I have 5 tabs in the mainPanel. Will it be possible to export all the mainPanel tabs into single pdf (with page scaling option) and getting a merged pdf output for all the tabs?
4. Is it possible to add a button for above 1, 2 and 3.

Here is a screenshot of my shiny app

[image]

Output after using the appshot() from webshot library.

[image]

But the output is not showing any tables and graph. My shiny app takes around 35-40 seconds to fetch the data for the selected date from database. It is because my database size is around 2 GB containing around 3.2 million rows. I am using the below code to generate the png output.

```
folder_address = 'E:/app.R'
appshot(folder_address, file="page1.png",port=8888)
```

How to make the appshot to wait for shiny to load the data?

Comment: What did you try so far? Some example code would be nice plus seeing what research effort you've done yourself.

Comment: Hi SeGa, I have added the screenshot of my shiny app. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you look at the **webshot** [package](https://github.com/wch/webshot) ? You can find some instructions [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/webshot/vignettes/intro.html)

Comment: Hi SeGa, I have tried the appshot and added the screenshot of output. Please have a look.

Comment: you can pass the `delay` argument to appshot, as it is passed further to the `webshot`function. So try `appshot(folder_address, file="page1.png",port=8888, delay = 60)`

Comment: Thanks @SeGa, it works. I am getting the output with all the tables and graphs in the first default tab. But how to control the width of the page. The length it is taken as per the content, so how to increase the width of the page.  Also how to get the output from other tabs. I am using the code `appshot(folder_address, file="page1.png",port=8888,delay=50,selector = "#Depot Ranks")` to select the **"Depot Ranks"** tab, but not working.

Comment: Looking at the help of webshots you will find all these arguments - `webshot(url = NULL, file = "webshot.png", vwidth = 992, vheight = 744, cliprect = NULL, selector = NULL, expand = NULL, delay = 0.2, zoom = 1, eval = NULL)` - so the width can be changed with `vwidth`. Without seeing the html of your page, its hard to find correct selectors. You probably have to write some JavaScript in the `eval`-argument, to simulate a click on the desired table, before taking the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks SeGa, `vwidth` works very well. For selecting the tabs I am exploring the `eval` option. Thanks a lot for your help.